# Remove Google Find My Device Password

Tags: samsung, google, password

A few weeks back I lost my Samsung Galaxy S7.  I came home and immediately did a Google Find My Device.  I added a message to the finder and a password to lock it.  Great.  That worked.  The phone was handed to the Police.  However, there is simply NO way at all to remove this password now.  The phone had no password before either.

Every possible solution I have tried but nothing removes this annoying password.

Maybe only a Factory Reset but thought I would see if anyone here has an answer.  I have searched high and low and can find no answer surprisingly to my question.

Comment: What happens if you enter the password? Have you checked security settings if the password has been set as regular lockscreen password?

Comment: Has anyone ever succeed in unlocking remote secured device at all? afaik google broke this feature years ago

Comment: Has anyone had any luck?

Answer (score 0):

As per google on their page:

> **Secure device**: Locks your phone with your PIN, pattern, or password.
> If you don't have a lock, you can set one. To help someone return your
> phone to you, you can add a message or phone number to the lock
> screen.
>
> **Erase device**: Permanently deletes all data on your phone (but
> might not delete SD cards). After you erase, Find My Device won't work
> on the phone. Important: If you find your phone after erasing, you'll
> likely need your Google Account password to use it again.

As the last line suggests - the password has to be Google Account Password

If you are looking at completely remove the password option from phone again you can do this...

**Procedure**

1. Open **Settings**.
2. Tap Security (on Samsung phones, tap **Lock Screen**)
3. Tap **Screen Lock**. Note: If prompted, enter your current password, PIN, or pattern.
4. Choose your screen lock preference: none, swipe, password, PIN, or pattern. (Choose **None** here)
5. Tap **Done**.